# IBM Lotus Notes - File\Application\Refresh design command

Tags: lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse, lotus-notes, lotus-designer

Does anybody knows if there is any way to set the default value for the "With design from Server" drop down field ???

The inconvenience is that I have quite a long list of servers and have to select the development server every time I refresh the design.

It would be handy to be able just to click on OK button in this dialog box, rather then browsing for the same server name again and again...

Comment: I have also a very long list of servers. But by simply start typing you narrow down this list quite easily. For me this is not a big deal, although there has to be "something" to set the server, because sometimes it starts with a special server here at my client...

Comment: Yes I know I can type in. Thats the quickest way to do it so far. But the

Comment: question still there how to set up the default value

Comment: Copy server name into clipboard

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. At least from my knowlegde this is not possible. Best option is trying what has already been suggested in the comments.

That said you can also change the design using the "load convert" command on the Domino server console (it's not just for converting mail boxes).

Ove